# Printing to receipt printer with PrintDocument does not print all content

Tags: c#

I'm trying to print a receipt to printer with the following code. The problem is that the receipt is not completely printed. I think it is printing just one page but I don't how to set the page numbers prior to print.

```
public void print()
{
    pdoc = new PrintDocument();
    PaperSize psize = new PaperSize("Custom", 450, 820);
    pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
    pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);
    pdoc.Print();
}

void pdoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 10);
    var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
    int startX = 5;
    int startY = 35;
    int Offset = 40;
    graphics.DrawString("             DIGITAL STORE               ", font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;
    graphics.DrawString("           ITEMS TO DELIVER             ", font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;
    string linea3 = string.Format("{0} Ticket#: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), data[1]);
    graphics.DrawString(linea3, font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;
    string linea4 = string.Format("NB#: {0}", data[2]);
    graphics.DrawString(linea4, font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;
    graphics.DrawString("Item ID      Weigth     Price     Type", font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;
    graphics.DrawString("----------------------------------------", font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;

    var cant = (data.Length - 12) / 6;

    var pos = 12;
    for (var i = 0; i < cant; i++)
    {
        var linea7 = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", data[pos++], data[pos++], data[pos++], data[pos++]);
        graphics.DrawString(linea7, font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
        Offset = Offset + 20;
        graphics.DrawString(data[pos++], font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
        Offset = Offset + 20;
        graphics.DrawString(data[pos++], font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
        Offset = Offset + 20;
        if (i != cant - 1)
            Offset = Offset + 20;
    }

    Offset = Offset + 20;
    string linea5 = string.Format("{0}: {1}", "Stock".PadRight(15), data[4]);
    graphics.DrawString(linea5, font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;
    string linea6 = string.Format("{0}: {1}", "Total peso".PadRight(15), data[5]);
    graphics.DrawString(linea6, font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;
    string linea71 = string.Format("{0}: {1}", "Total TAR1".PadRight(15), data[6]);
    graphics.DrawString(linea71, font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;
    string linea8 = string.Format("{0}: {1}", "Total TAR2".PadRight(15), data[7]);
    graphics.DrawString(linea8, font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;
    string linea9 = string.Format("{0}: {1} = {2}", "Total Vol".PadRight(15), data[8], data[9]);
    graphics.DrawString(linea9, font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;
    string linea10 = string.Format("Items retirados: {0}", data[10]);
    graphics.DrawString(linea10, font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;
    string linea11 = string.Format("Usuario: {0}", data[11]);
    graphics.DrawString(linea11, font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 60;
    graphics.DrawString("----------------------------------------", font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 40;
    string linea12 = string.Format("{0}", data[3].Replace("|", " "));
    graphics.DrawString(linea12, font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 40;
    graphics.DrawString("            SIGNATUE           ", font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 40;
    graphics.DrawString("*******THANKS FOR WORK WITH US********", font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 10;
    if (data[0] == "R")
        graphics.DrawString("**********************************", font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    graphics.DrawString("a", font, brush, startX, startY + Offset);
    e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

Comment: The for cicle is to print 6 attribute for each the item to be delivered. It can be any number of itmes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article on MSDN: [How to: Print a Multi-Page Text File in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwbe712d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Since your task is very similar to printing of a text file, I believe this should help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is you may change the printer's Paper size in Layout > Printer Preferences. Select 'User Defined Paper Size' to create a new size of paper length as per you required. The default length size is similar to the A4 size.